# win32com.client.Dispatch() 32-64 bits Programs

Tags: python, com, 32bit-64bit, win32com

i'm trying to create a com object with win32com in python. Using theses command :

```
import win32com.client
com_nxn = win32com.client.Dispatch("NxNNamespace.NxNNamespaceHelper")
```

I tried 2 times, first on my 64 bit python2.6 install with win32 64 bit install.
I was able to make work the import win32com.client line.
But the con_nxn command still doensn't work and give me the following error:

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 85, in _GetGoodDispatch
IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
```

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Classe non enregistr\xe9e', None, None)

On an other part with a python and win32com 32 Bit installation, all work fine, my Com object is created.
I think the problem is that the software i'm trying to instantiate is in 32 bits and doesn't provide a 64bit Com object

So my Question is : How can i make it work on my python 64Bit?
Can i use a win32Com 32 bit by some strange way (copying dll) on my python 64Bit?
Or maybe the problem is not what i think it is, in that case if someOne can enlight me, i would be gratefull, i'm a total begginner with com Object :D

(i'm on windows 7 64 bits)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how the object is implemented, you may be able to just
change the activation context by adding clsctx=pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER
to the args passed to Dispatch.  If that doesn't work, then try
CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_32_BIT_SERVER (0x40000) for the clsctx.
If neither of those work, you still may be able to create an out of process proxy for the
application using Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Component Services.

Answer (score 0):

try this. i not sure in this solution
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>.\msiexec.exe /i '*path of application*'

addition information is [here](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Problem-using-win32com-client-Dispatch-on-Win7-64bit-td1957248.html)